# What's wrong with my short minimax algorithm for Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, minimax

```
    CHOICE = 0;
    def score(State, Depth):
        if(conditionX(State)):
            return 10 - Depth
        elif(conditionO(State)):
            return Depth - 10
        return 0

    def minimax(State, Depth):
        if(condition(State)): return score(State, Depth)
        scores =[-1000]
        moves = [0]
        possibleState = ()
        for index in range(1,10):
            if(not index in State[0] and not index in State[1]):
                if(State[2]%2==0):
                    newState = State[1]
                    newState.append(index)
                    possibleState += (State[0],newState,State[2]+1)
                    scores.append(minimax(possibleState, Depth + 1))
                    moves.append(index)
                elif(State[2]%2!=0):
                    newState = State[0]
                    newState.append(index)
                    possibleState += (newState,State[1],State[2]+1)
                    scores.append(minimax(possibleState, Depth + 1))
                    moves.append(index)
        maxItem = max(scores)
        maxIndex = scores.index(maxItem)
        global CHOICE
        CHOICE = moves[maxIndex]
        return max(scores)
```

I don't know why the code always plays for once instead of return every possible move. printing states every time it runs show that it only run once like this

([5], [], 0)

([5], [1], 1)

([5, 2], [1], 2)

([5, 2], [1, 3], 3)

([5, 2, 4], [1, 3], 4)

([5, 2, 4], [1, 3, 6], 5)

([5, 2, 4, 7], [1, 3, 6], 6)

([5, 2, 4, 7], [1, 3, 6, 8], 7)

([5, 2, 4, 7, 9], [1, 3, 6, 8], 8)

0
which is only once and not very smart moves either. Explanation for the function I did not include:

conditionX check if X wins

conditionO check if O wins

conditionDraw check if draws

condition just check any of the above happened

The State is always a tuple which contain X coors, O coors and turns

Comment: It would be super useful if you explain what a state in your code is and for what it stands for. No one likes to guess what are you trying to do with your code.

Comment: I think I did. Maybe you missed it or it is too ambiguous?